# How to migrate MYSQL database with having different column name?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-migration

I have two database `old.sql` & `new.sql`.

I have user table named `user` in `new.sql`. and  `users` in `old.sql`.

table structure for `user` from `new.sql`

```
--
-- Table structure for table `user`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phoneNumber` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `role` enum('USER','ADMIN') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'USER',
  `createdOn` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `User_email_key` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `User_phoneNumber_key` (`phoneNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

and `users` from `old.sql`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `roleId` int NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `resetPasswordExpires` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `resetPasswordToken` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `roleId` (`roleId`),
  CONSTRAINT `Users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`roleId`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=884 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

now I want to migrate user from old database to new database.
this is only one table, we have many tables to migrate data.

how can I achieve that ?

also we have done normalization in new database like
`old.sql` one table separated in 2 or 3 new tables in new database.

These DBs are on the same MySQL instance.

Comment: ok thank you. I changed. any solution for this?

Comment: Which tool do you use when migrating?

Comment: If you want to  migrate why are the tables different ? Is it the `user` table on `mysql` database ?

Comment: I am not using any tool, because table name is different. @jarlh

Comment: As i see you need to write a program for migrating data 
where you will take into account all details you need

Comment: we have developed new version from scratch. @ErgestBasha

Comment: ok, also we have done normalization in new database like 
`old.sql` one table separated in 2 or 3 new tables in new database. @Alexus

Comment: do you have any examples for program to do this? @Alexus

Comment: You will loose a part of the data while copying the data into new structure. *also we have done normalization in new database like old.sql one table separated in 2 or 3 new tables in new database.* Provide tables set which can accept old data completely. *how can I achieve that ?* You must create custom SQL script which will copy the data into new structure without data loss and with relations saving. *I have two database old.sql & new.sql.* Are these DBs processed on the same MySQL instance?

Comment: yes, these DBs processed on the same MySQL instance. @Akina

Comment: In this case the copying process is simple enough. Copy base data with according query, then copy data into dictionary tables using joined old and new tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple script like:

```
INSERT INTO
  user (id, email, password, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, role, createdOn)
SELECT
  id, email, password, firstName, lastName, null, IF(roleId = 1, 'ADMIN', 'USER'), created
FROM users;
```

Just set correct roleId for condition and remove id if you need a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Tiny example of the data transferring realization with some remarks: [DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a535e8aa70f3b248a33ac6b6465ac2e)